# DAX formula that finds specific and separate words in a text string

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have a table which contains text ('TextString'[Text]) and I need a DAX formula in a calculated column which can find specific words taken from another table 'Matchlist'[Keyword].

However, the formula must ignore instances when the keyword is found in the string as part of another word. For instance, the text string "Modification Cost" contains the keyword "cat" but it should be ignored because it is a part of another word "modification" and is not a separate word.

Can you please help me to modify the below formula, so it would take into account this additional requirement?

```
=IF(
  SUMX('Matchlist',
       FIND(
            UPPER('Matchlist'[Keyword]),
            UPPER('TextString'[Text])
            ,,0
           )
      ) > 0,
  "YES",
  "No"
 )
```

I am using Power Pivot and Excel 365. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way might be to split the original text into separate columns using Edit queries in data view, and Split Column by delimiter (which could be ' ').

You could then use COUNTROWS something along the lines of

```
    =CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'MatchList' ),
    UPPER ( 'TextString'[Text] ) = UPPER ( 'MatchList'[Path1] )
        || UPPER ( 'TextString'[Text] ) = UPPER ( 'MatchList'[Path2] )
        || UPPER ( 'TextString'[Text] ) = UPPER ( 'MatchList'[Path3] )
        etc...
)
```

Comment: Including a link is fine, but you should include an explanation and supporting code for your answer.